# How do I write a set of positive odd numbers as set literals

Tags: python

I know this is probably basic but I’m new to python
So far I’ve got

```
S = set()
for i in range (0, 7):
S add ( i*2 + 1)
```

But I don’t know if I used set literals as I don’t really know what they are

Comment: Can you ask the problem more clearly?

Comment: A set _literal_ would be something like `{1, 3, 5, 7, ..., 13}`. Did you mean a set comprehension, e.g. `{2*i+1 for i in range(7)}`? Or use `range` with step and convert to `set`: `set(range(1, 14, 2))`

Comment: The clarify things, the question that I needed help was: Write these sets as literal value, the first 7 positive odd numbers

Answer (score 0):

##### Option 1

```
def createSet(n)->set:
    return set(range(1, n+1, 2))
    
print(createSet(7))
print(createSet(10))
print(createSet(15))
```

Output:

```
{1, 3, 5, 7}
{1, 3, 5, 7, 9}
{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15}
```

##### Option 2

```
def comprehension(n)->set:
    return {i for i in range(1, n+1, 2)}

print(comprehension(7))
print(comprehension(10))
print(comprehension(15))
```

The Output is the same

```
{1, 3, 5, 7}
{1, 3, 5, 7, 9}
{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15}
```

#### 2*i+1

In both options `n` is the upper limit. If you want to do it with `2*i+1` you can do it like this

```
def comprehension(n):
    return {2*i+1 for i in range(n)}

print(comprehension(7))
print(comprehension(10))
print(comprehension(15))
```

Now the Output would look like this:

```
{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13}
{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19}
{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29}
```

Since I can see from the comments that you only want to have the first 7 odd numbers, this option is probably out of the question.